# String replacement using Python 3 re.sub

Tags: regex, python-3.x

```
p = re.compile('Dhcp Server .*? add scope .*? (.*?) ')
test_str = 'Dhcp Server \\server1 add scope 10.0.1.0 255.255.255.0 "area1"'
subst = "255.255.254.0"
re.sub(p, subst, test_str)
```

The output is `255.255.254.0`.  What i am trying to get is this:

```
Dhcp Server \\server1 add scope 10.0.1.0 255.255.254.0 "area1"'
```

I can't simply use string replace because `server1` and `10.0.1.0` will by dynamic.

How can I get my desired result when using Python 3.5?  I looked at other SO questions, but did not find one quite like my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **capturing groups** for this:

```
test_str = 'Dhcp Server \\server1 add scope 10.0.1.0 255.255.255.0 "area1"'

print re.sub(r'(Dhcp Server .*? add scope [\d.]+) [\d.]+ (.*)', r"\1 255.255.254.0 \2", test_str)
```

We are capturing text before replacement position into `\1` and part after replacement is available in `\2`.

**Output:**

```
Dhcp Server \\server1 add scope 10.0.1.0 255.255.254.0 "area1"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have it backwards. You use capture groups for the parts of the expression that you want to copy, not the parts you want to replace. Then you use a back-reference in the replacement string to copy them.

```
p = re.compile('(Dhcp Server .*? add scope .*? ).*? ')
test_str = 'Dhcp Server \\server1 add scope 10.0.1.0 255.255.255.0 "area1"'
subst = r"\g<1>255.255.254.0 "
re.sub(p, subst, test_str)
```

Comment: This returns: `'U5.255.254.0 "area1"'`

Comment: Need to use `\g<1>` because it was looking for group number 125.

Comment: Can you please explain what is meant by "group number 125"?

Comment: When backslash is followed by a number, it means to substitute that capture group. My original answer had `\1255.255.254.0` in the replacement, so it treated `\125` as a back-reference to group number `125`.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could just match the parts you want and then reconstruct the line (particularly if you want to know if you have made a replacement):

```
p = re.compile('(Dhcp Server .*? add scope .*? )(.*?)( .*)')
test_str = 'Dhcp Server \\server1 add scope 10.0.1.0 255.255.255.0 "area1"'
subst = "255.255.254.0"
match = p.match(test_str)
if match:
  replaced = match.group(1) + subst + match.group(3)
```